# How to avoid SQL Server using default row estimate for missing values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I got a table with a couple of million rows with a `Status` column which is 2nd column in a non-clustered index.
The status is `char(10)` and contains "New", "Processing", "Processed" and "Failed"

A polling function checks for new rows

```
SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM Table WHERE firstColumnInIdex = 1 AND Status = 'New' ORDER BY Id
```

(It is actually an update to status "Processing" and some other differences but it doesn't matter here)

The query uses the non-clustered index but the row estimate is ~30% of rows so the memory grant is in the GB-range.

My testing shows the problem is the statistics. Since there are normally no rows with status "New" in the table, "New" is not present in the statistics (which says millions "Processed" and thousands "Failed"). SQL Server seems go for a default estimate, in this case ~30% of rows, if the value is not found in the statistics.

I added a row to the table with status "New" and created new statistics with `FULLSCAN NORECOMPUTE`. (So it becomes millions "Processed", thousands "Failed" and 1 "New")

Now the row estimate is 1 row and the query cost goes down from 82 to 6 with a small memory grant.

(dropping the statistics causes 30% again)

While this trick solves the problem it feels like a hack which might stop working some day (e.g. some future dba finds this outdated statistics and deletes/updates it).

Is there a better way to solve this? e.g.

- using integer status instead?
- Making SQL Server aware of the "New" status with a foreign key or constraint?

Version is 2016SP1

Comment: Can you store the "New" rows in a seperate table from all the other rows and move them to the main table once processed?

Comment: @MJH, yes but then I will probably need a view combining them to get a complete picture of not started, in progress, recently finished etc. Either that or trigger storing id of new rows in a separate table (or just keep a dummy "New" row in the table to get statistics correct).

Comment: Are you sure that the status field is `CHAR(10)` - a fixed length field rather than VARCHAR? Also note that 'Processing' (as 11 characters) won't fit into it.

Comment: @seanb, 'Processing' is 10 characters :-)

Comment: Haha oops. You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I find useful is a [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15).

Assuming this is a queue and things start with status 'new', you

- Select one or all of the 'new' rows (getting the PK IDs)
- Act on those IDs
- Update the status according to IDs

In these cases, you could create a filtered index which is basically just an up-to-date list of all the rows with status 'new'.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_myindex ON [myTable] 
([ID])
WHERE (Status = 'New')
```

Note - the index will be very 'hot' e.g., have a lot of changes (as soon as they're no longer 'new', they get removed from the index).

However, the idea is to keep so small that it doesn't really matter.

Make sure the index has all the fields you need to identify the relevant rows (e.g., your PK) to keep it as simple/small as possible, and see if it works.

### UPDATE FOLLOWING COMMENTS

The issues is probably related to the 'Ascending key problem' - feel free to research and review.

I may have made a minor mistake above - often filtered indexes work better if you actually include the field you're filtering on. Therefore the following may be better.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_myindex ON [myTable] 
([ID], [Status])
WHERE (Status = 'New')
```

Regarding the approach in the solution - the idea is that we're going to completely ignore statistics. Instead, we actually create a temporary table with the relevant number of rows, and those will instead limit the cardinality estimates.

For testing, I have a table called 'test' that has about 1.5 million rows, with an ID PK and 4 columns with UUIDs (essentially random data).

I use this to create a new table 'test2' with a status column. Approx 80% of these have status 'Processed', 10% status 'Processing', 10% status 'Failed'.

I then insert a new row with status 'New'. Note that the statistics *do not update*.

However, I then use the filtered index to identify the relevant rows by putting them into a temp table - and using that table for further processing.

SETUP

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'test2', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Test2;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test2](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col3] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col4] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col5] [varchar](100) NULL,
    
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
 );
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_test2_StatusNew] ON [dbo].[test2] ([ID] ASC, [Status] ASC)
    WHERE ([Status]='New');
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test2 (ID, Status, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
    SELECT ID, CASE WHEN ID % 12 < 10 THEN 'Processed' WHEN ID % 12 = 10 THEN 'Processing' ELSE 'Failed' END,
          Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
    FROM dbo.Test;
GO

CREATE STATISTICS [S_Status] ON [dbo].[test2]([Status]);
GO

DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('dbo.Test2', 'S_Status');
/*
RANGE_HI_KEY  RANGE_ROWS EQ_ROWS   DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
Failed        0          141420    0                    1
Processed     0          1417080   0                    1
Processing    0          141420    0                    1
*/
```

Here's my stored procedure - it starts with flagging the appropriate rows (changing their status to 'Processing') and recording their IDs.

The IDs are then used to process the rows in the table, and then update the status again to 'Processed'.

For brevity here, I haven't included any transactions or error-checking.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTest2News
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #IDs_to_process (ID int PRIMARY KEY);

    UPDATE      test2
        SET     Status = 'Processing'
        OUTPUT  deleted.ID
        INTO    #IDs_to_process
        WHERE   Status = 'New';

    UPDATE      test2
        SET     Col2 = NEWID(),
                Col3 = NEWID(),
                Col4 = NEWID(),
                Col5 = NEWID()
        FROM    test2
                INNER JOIN #IDs_to_Process IDs ON test2.ID = IDs.ID;

    UPDATE      test2
        SET     Status = 'Processed'
        FROM    test2
                INNER JOIN #IDs_to_Process IDs ON test2.ID = IDs.ID;

END;
```

I then add a new row (with status 'New') into Test2. When checking the stats, they haven't changed (not enough changes have occurred to force an update).

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.test2 ORDER BY ID DESC; -- Getting the latest value for next step
/* Max ID = 1699920 */

INSERT INTO dbo.Test2 (ID, Status, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
SELECT 1699921, 'New', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL;

DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('dbo.Test2', 'S_Status');
/*  Same as above  */
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('dbo.Test2', 'IX_test2_StatusNew');
/*  No records represented in stats  */
GO
```

Now, the final steps

- Run `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;` to see processing stats
- Also set 'Include actual execution plan' to see estimates vs actuals etc

```
EXEC UpdateTest2News
```

Here are a cleaned-up version stats - which are pretty darn good.

```
Stats summary

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

Table '#IDs_to_process___...________________0000000000BC'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2
Table 'test2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 14 ms.


SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 25 ms, elapsed time = 25 ms.

Table 'test2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 11
Table '#IDs_to_process________...__________0000000000BC'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 593 ms.


SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

Table 'test2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3
Table '#IDs_to_process_____...______0000000000BC'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 45 ms.


 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 61 ms,  elapsed time = 683 ms.
```

And here is the execution plan/etc, and estimates vs actuals are good too.

[image]

---

Note - It *does* remember/cache the execution plans, which could turn into an issue when you have vastly different numbers of 'new' rows.

If needed, you can put `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on statements 2 or 3 within the stored procedure, so it takes the new estimates of the number of rows.

Also the command `UPDATE STATISTICS test2 (IX_test2_StatusNew) WITH fullscan` is trivial to run (as there are almost no rows in that index) if desired - that may help in your situation.

Comment: Initial testing shows it works but I must include all columns from the query or it will go for the clustered index. Thanks. I'll test it some more tomorrow before marking as answer

Comment: One alternative is to just pull the PKs from the index to start with e.g.,  insert the PKs into into a temp table (which has the same PK as the original table), and the use that temp table in a join to the original table. If you're doing complex processing, this temp table may already exist in your process. I'm not saying this approach is better, but could be - it really depends on your specific situation and how much of a problem adding a wide index is.

Comment: I tested this a bit more and unfortunately the partial index doesn't work :-(. There must be a statistics containing status "New" or default is still used. Just having "New" in a filter does not make any difference.

Comment: Currently considering adding a trigger to put the index of new rows into a second table. Just seems strange I have never heard anyone else having this problem before.

Comment: I've done a big update to the answer - clarifying how I suggest using the filtered index.

Comment: Thanks, your new code is more or less what I'm doing. There must be something in the extra filtering I have in my code causing it. I will not spend more time on it and your test code is working for me as well so I mark it as answer. (Easiest solution for me was to keep a dummy row with status 'New' in the table which will never be hit for other reasons)

Comment: That's pretty clever @adrianm. In practice statistics will always show 1 for 'new', so it won't guess the number as an unknown.